# How to get status of community publish

Tags: salesforcedx, sf

We are using in CI/CD command to publish the community

`sf community publish --name 'My Customer Site'`

This operation is asynchronous and it is not possible to run publish of another community.
Is there a command to check the status of the community publish process?